# httpOnly cookies are visible

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt

i am creating jwt token based sessions and passing that token to client with httpOnly argument but the cookie are visible in browser here is photo: [image]
and here is the code

```
const token = jwt.sign({id :payload}, process.env.SECRET, {
            expiresIn: 10
        })

        console.log(token)
     res.cookie('token', token, {
            httpOnly: true
        });
```

what is the problem why is "token cookie" visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies)

> To prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, HttpOnly cookies are
>   inaccessible to JavaScript's Document.cookie API; they are only sent
>   to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions
>   don't need to be available to JavaScript, and the HttpOnly flag should
>   be set.

The HttpOnly flag doesn't prevent the cookie to be visible, but prevents being access from JavaScript. Cookies can't be hidden